# Will 2 years of non relevant work ex affect ms in cs prospects?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, united-states, changing-fields, india

I have completed Bachelor's in Computer Science ( from India) with an 8.7 CGPA. During my engineering I've done a couple of relevant internships and published a couple of papers. After graduating, I've done a two years non-relevant job in a reputed bank.

Will this non-relevant work experience hurt my chances of getting admit in a good university for MS in CS? (in USA)

Comment: Look at the entry criteria for those universities that you are interested in. As Buffy said, it is different for each institutions

Answer (score 1):

Every university is different, but two years shouldn't be a big problem as long as you haven't lost the knowledge you once had. But in the US, even that is less of a problem as the MS usually involves a lot of course work.

Most admissions systems are looking for evidence of success that you can demonstrate. If your record is good and you can get good letters of recommendation you will have a chance. And, the internships and papers are a plus, of course.

But note that, depending on where you apply, you may find tremendous competition for limited slots. Don't make your search for a university too narrow.